# Haskell: Property Based Testing for Higher Order Function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, quickcheck, property-based-testing

I have two properties that a function `foo` must satisfy:

```
prop_1 :: [Int] -> Bool
prop_1 xs = foo xs id == xs 

prop_2 :: [Int] -> (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> Bool
prop_2 xs f g = foo (foo xs f) g == foo xs (g . f)
```

I am trying to check whether the above properties satisfy the following function using quickCheck:

```
foo :: [a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
foo xs f = []
```

When I tried running quickCheck with prop_2 I get the following error:

```
quickCheck(prop_2)

<interactive>:18:1: error:
     No instance for (Show (Int -> Int))
        arising from a use of 'quickCheck'
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
     In the expression: quickCheck (prop_2)
      In an equation for 'it': it = quickCheck (prop_2)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error and how I can resolve it. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: The arguments of `prop_2` must be `Show`able, since `QuickCheck` should be able to show with what parameters the `prop_2` was disproven.

Comment: You can import `ShowFunctions` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation on `QuickCheck`](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual.html#19) says:

> However, before we can test such a property, we must see to it that **function values can be printed** (in case a counter-example is found). That is, function types must be instances of class `Show`. To arrange this, you **must import module `ShowFunctions`** into every module containing higher-order properties of this kind. If a counter-example is found, function values will be displayed as `"<function>"`

So you can fix this by importing a module like:

```
import Text.Show.Functions

prop_1 :: [Int] -> Bool
prop_1 xs = foo xs id == xs 

prop_2 :: [Int] -> (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> Bool
prop_2 xs f g = foo (foo xs f) g == foo xs (g . f)
```

Comment: It's really much better to use the `Fun` type as Alexey Romanov explains than to use a bogus orphan instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use QuickCheck's support for [generation of random shrinkable, showable functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#g:14) by changing the property to

```
prop_2 :: [Int] -> Fun Int Int -> Fun Int Int -> Bool
prop_2 xs (Fn f) (Fn g) = foo (foo xs f) g == foo xs (g . f)
```

and then you'll see something more useful than `<function>` for counterexamples.

Comment: What is <function> in quickCheck? I tried running quickCheck with another property and I got the following result: Failed (after 2 tests and 1 shrink) <function> "" "".

Comment: It isn't "in QuickCheck", it's how the instance in Text.Show.Functions works (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Show-Functions.html)