# Haskell: Understanding QuickCheck with higher order function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, quickcheck, property-based-testing

I have the function `foo`:

```
foo :: [a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
foo [] f = []
foo (x:xs) f = foo xs f
```

And the following two properties that it must satisfy:

```
prop_1 :: [Int] -> Bool
prop_1 xs = foo xs id == xs 

prop_2 :: [Int] -> (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> Bool
prop_2 xs f g = foo (foo xs f) g == foo xs (g . f)
```

When I tried to test the function using quickCheck, I get the following error:

```
 Ambiguous type variable 't0' arising from a use of '=='
      prevents the constraint '(Eq t0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what 't0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (Either a b)
          -- Defined in 'Data.Either'
        instance Eq GeneralCategory -- Defined in 'GHC.Unicode'
        instance Eq Ordering -- Defined in 'ghc-prim-0.5.0.0:GHC.Classes'
        ...plus 24 others
        ...plus 107 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
      In the expression: foo (foo xs f) g == foo xs (g . f)
      In an equation for 'prop_2':
          prop_2 xs f g = foo (foo xs f) g == foo xs (g . f)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error and how I can solve it. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: DId you wrote the `prop_2` in the *shell*? Did you use `:{` and `:}` to write both the signature and the function in the same "block"?

Comment: No, I had prop_2 in a file with prop_1 and foo.

Comment: It looks as if Haskell is not able to understand the type of `foo xs (g . f)`, so that usually means the type signatures are not saying it is an `[Int]` here.

Comment: Can you share a compilable example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I tried compiling and running your properties. I couldn't reproduce your error message, but I found two other issues: Firstly, your function `foo` is equivalent to `const []`, so your first property will always fail. Secondly, `prop_2` can't be run by `quickCheck` because there is no `Show (Int -> Int)` instance (`quickCheck` requires this so it can print counter examples)

Comment: @sara: the second issue was covered in the previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805030/haskell-property-based-testing-for-higher-order-function

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate your error message with the following program.  Note that the signature for `foo` is commented out:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Text.Show.Functions

-- foo :: [a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
foo [] f = []
foo (x:xs) f = foo xs f

prop_1 :: [Int] -> Bool
prop_1 xs = foo xs id == xs

prop_2 :: [Int] -> (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> Bool
prop_2 xs f g = foo (foo xs f) g == foo xs (g . f)

main = do
  quickCheck prop_1
  quickCheck prop_2
```

If I put the `foo` signature back in, it type-checks fine.  The tests fail of course, since `foo` isn't doing what you intend it to do.

The issue is that the version of `foo` you have here has inferred signature:

```
foo :: [a] -> b -> [c]
```

so in `prop_2`, the type of the list elements for the top-most `foo` calls can't be inferred to resolve the correct `(==)` operation.

If you replace `foo` with a correct version:

```
foo :: [a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
foo [] f = []
foo (x:xs) f = f x : foo xs f
```

then the tests pass *and* you can actually comment out the signature again because the correct type can be inferred.